# Unordered_map iterator throwing error

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-map

I have this code:

```
int solution(int K, const vector<int> &A) {
  int count=0,size,comp=0;
  unordered_map<long,long> map;

  size = A.size();
  if(size==0)
      return 0;

  for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
      map[A[i]] = i;
  }

  for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
      comp = K-A[i];
      unordered_map<long,long>::const_iterator index = map.find(comp); //error here
      if(index == map.end())
          continue;
      else{
          count++;
      }
  }
  cout << "final count: " << count << endl;
  return count;    
}
```

I'm getting an error for invalid operands and am unable to figure out what I'm doing wrong. I've tried switching iterators but it also might be my compiler. I'm using this to compile:

clang++ -stdlib=libc++ -std=gnu++11 workingpairs.cpp

My errors are: expected ';' at end of declaration
        unordered_map::const_iterator index = map.find(comp);

indirection requires pointer operand ('int' invalid)
        __table_.__insert_unique(*__first);

in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::unordered_map, std::__1::equal_to,
      std::__1::allocator > >::insert' requested here

Any insight/help would be appreciated!

**EDIT:**

I've gone back and fixed the error.

Comment: This would be a good place to use `auto index = map.find(comp);`

Comment: @Blastfurnace instead of the const_interator? or in addition to it?

Comment: I would just use the [`auto`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) keyword. The compiler already knows the type of the expression `map.find(comp)` so it will declare `index` as that type. No more typos on those tedious iterator declarations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed `::` in below statement

```
unordered_map<long,long>const_iterator
```

should be:

```
unordered_map<long,long>::const_iterator
```

Comment: Wow... thanks!

I still have another error: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::unordered_map<long, long, std::__1::hash<long>, std::__1::equal_to<long>,
      std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<const long, long> > >::insert<int>' requested here
        map.insert(A[i],i);.

Do you know what that is?

Comment: that's because `map.insert(A[i],i);`, insert can take pair, not key/value directly